# .NET Core Web API IIS deploy local machine

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have created a Web API in the new .NET CORE framework, it grabs data from our server on our domain.(local machine also sit on domain).

Deploy with IIS express is fine it runs and works.

Currently built a quick xamarin app to talk to my web API, however Ive foudn oout theres no wayt to connect to my local IISExpress when testing on my phone.

So I published my web api to my local machine (rightr clicked on solution publish).

I set up an application pool in IIS on my machine, set it to unmanaged code.
I then created a virtual directory and pointed to that directory, i then converted it to an application and assigned it to my app pool.

When i naviagte to the URL "http://localhost/MereWebAPI" i get a blank page, as to be expected.  So i then finish the url with the api "http://localhost/MereWebAPI/api/name/1",  however i still get a blank page.

So i tried my other controllers that perform simple "GET" but get a blank screen with "[]" instead.

Am i missing any steps here?

EDIT: my appsettings.json

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection":     "Server=server\\instance;Database=DEV01;Trusted_Connection=True"
},
"Logging": {
"IncludeScopes": false,
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "System": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Information"
}
}
}
```

EDIT: my publish options in project.json

```
"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "**/*.cshtml",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
]
},
```

Comment: Verify all entries like conn string etc in published `appsettings.json` This usually happens when such configuration fails in published version and works fine in your development environment.

Comment: Ive updated my question with appsettings it looks fine to me, how can i verfy this?

Comment: Have you tried using a REST client to see the http response and any additional details?  Also, does your project.json include all the files necessary for your API in the publishOptions section?

Comment: IIS express works fine and talks, however IIS doesnt work with the publish,   i simply browser checked this, i do have an app and also have postman installed nothing works with IIS, but all works with express

Comment: Have you installed the .Net Core Windows Server Hosting Bundle [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827547)?

Comment: Yup it was one of the first things i did

Answer (score 0):

You need more information.

**Enable and check the application logs** at `.\logs\stdout`.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add 
         name="aspNetCore" 
         path="*" 
         verb="*" 
         modules="AspNetCoreModule" 
         resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore 
         processPath=".\MyApp.exe" 
         arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" 
         stdoutLogEnabled="false"                  <--- enable
         stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />          <--- set path
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Check the IIS logs** (you probably do NOT have to enable them first). Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application. To drill down, you can Filter Current Log... by Event level et cetera.

[image: IIS Application Logs]